# What is the use of commas in an assignment?

Tags: python, syntax

I was reading another page on fibonacci sequence:

[How do I print a fibonacci sequence to the nth number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820601/how-do-i-print-a-fibonacci-sequence-to-the-nth-number-in-python)

and I was wondering if anyone can break down what is happening and how this specific line works.  I dont fully understand how "cur" and "i" is changing and such.

```
cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1
```

it was part of the fibonacci function

```
def fib(n):
    cur = 1
    old = 1
    i = 1
    while (i < n):
        cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1
    return cur
```

Comment: `cur, old, i = cur+old, cur, i+1` is equivalent to saying `cur=cur+old`, `old=cur`, `i=i+1`.

Comment: The Python term is ["sequence [un\]packing"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), also sometimes referred to as ["destructing assignment"](http://robert-lujo.com/post/40871820711/python-destructuring).

Comment: That loop should really be a `for`.

Answer (score 3):

The line you gave is equivalent to this:

```
cur, old, i = (cur+old, cur, i+1)
```

which is using a technique known as [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867891/2555451)*.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> x, y, z = (1, 2, 3)  # Parenthesis are optional here
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
3
>>>
```

---

In a longer form, your line is equivalent to this:

```
tmp = cur
cur = cur+old
old = tmp
i = i+1
```

which can be simplified to:

```
tmp = cur
cur += old
old = tmp
i += 1
```

---

***Note:**  Actually, it has quite a few names.  In addition to unpacking, a very common one is [multiple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182573/2555451).  @user2864740 also mentioned two more names in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715583/python-syntax-use-of-commas/21715613#comment32837617_21715583).

Answer (score 3):

More generally speaking, a commatized list of l-values used as an l-value in Python unpacks an iterable from the right-hand side into the parts of the left-hand side.

In your case, this means that the right-hand side creates a three-tuple of the values `cur+old`, `cur` and `i+1`, which is then unpacked into `cur`, `old` and `i`, respectively, so that it is the same as saying:

```
old = cur
cur = cur + old
i = i + 1
```

However, it is more useful, since `cur` isn't clobbered before `old` has been assigned to. It can also be used much more generally -- the left-hand side can consist of any l-values and the right-hand side can be any iterable, and you can do things like these:

```
a, b, c = range(3)
```

or

```
d = [0] * 10
d[3], d[7] = 1, 2
```

or

```
e, f, g = d[2:5]
```

In Python3, you can also used asterisk expressions to unpack "the rest" of an iterable; for instance, like this

```
h, *i, j = range(5)
# h will be 0, j will be 4, and i will be [1, 2, 3]
```

That doesn't work in Python2, however.

For the details, this is covered in [section 7.2 of the language reference](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Comment: I had no idea about your last use-case! So if I only want the first and last results of my generator, I can do `first, *_, last = gen(x)`? Amazing!