# Python return one-liner behaves differently than multiple liner code

Tags: python

I was practicing Fibonacci sequence generating in python and following example of memoization from [How do I print a fibonacci sequence to the nth number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820601/how-do-i-print-a-fibonacci-sequence-to-the-nth-number-in-python).

Then I encountered one interesting difference using return one-liner and not. For example, the example code is given below. In the first example, we do not use return one-liner and it runs very fast, however, in the second example we use return one-liner and it runs very slow.

Aren't they supposed to be the same?

## Without one-liner

```
def memoize(func):
    memo = dict()
    def decorated(n):
        if n not in memo:
            memo[n] = func(n)
        return memo[n]

    return decorated

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print([ fib(i) for i in range(100,110)]) # runs very fast
```

## With one-liner return

```
def memoize(func):
    memo = dict()
    def decorated(n):
        return func(n) if n not in memo else memo[n]

    return decorated

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print([ fib(i) for i in range(100,110)]) # very slow
```

**Question**
Aren't they supposed to be the same?
Why the return one-liner is much much slower than another one?
Can we write one-liner with different wordings so that it is equally fast?

Comment: The one-liner does not modify the contents of `memo`.

Comment: 2. The second one is slower because you're never saving anything in `memo`, presumably.

Comment: A correct one-liner would look something like `return memo[n] if n in memo else memo.setdefault(n, func(n))`. (The conditional expression prevents `func(n)` from being evaluated if the lookup would, in fact, succeed.)

Comment: @chepner, I tested your answer and it runs very very fast.

Comment: If you care about lines of code I can compress your entire `memorize` function to one line: `from functools import lru_cache as memorize`. This is written in c and will be much faster than anything you can reproduce in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Comment: @FHTMitchell  I tried using meorize but  this gives `TypeError: Expected maxsize to be an integer or None`

Comment: @astro123 - It is "memoize" not memorize

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, I am in learning phase, sorry for ignorances, but I simply used the @lru_cache  decorator to the function `fib(n)` and it does not work and gives above error.

Comment: @astro123 the documentation says you must use `@lru_cache(maxsize=<integer value or None>)` instead of simply `@lru_cache`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = func(n)
    return memo[n]
```

Is not the same as

```
    return func(n) if n not in memo else memo[n]
```

The one-liner does not modify the contents of memo. If you want to compare apples to apples then try:

```
    if n not in memo:
        return func(n)
    return memo[n]
```

For optimizing your one liner, and saving the dictionary value, you should change the one-liner to:

```
    return memo[n] if n in memo else memo.setdefault(n, func(n))
```

Beyond learning how memoize works, you should look into using [functools lru_cache's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) memoize, which is "written in C and will be much faster than anything you can reproduce in Python."

Hat tip to meowgoesthedog, chepner, & FHTMitchell.

Comment: lol, instead of showing how to optimize the one-liner properly, you show how to de-optimize the 3-liner.

Comment: @Barmar This is python. Aggressively lowering line count is discouraged.

Comment: @FHTMitchell And the point of writing a `memoize` function is that you write it once and forget about it -- there's nothing gained from writing it tersely.